# Use custom ansible variables per customer

Tags: ansible

I'm trying to figure out what is the best strategy to use custom variables on my ansible-playbooks/ansible-roles.
What I'm doing is at this time is:

---

Customer1:

- Create a new inventory file with Customer1 devices on `inventories/customer1.ini`
- Overwrite customer variables on `vars/controls.yml`
- Execute my ansible-playbook/ansible-role for Customer1 `ansible-playbook -i inventories/customer1.ini site.yml`

Customer2:

- Create a new inventory file with Customer2 devices on `inventories/customer2.ini`
- Overwrite customer variables on `vars/controls.yml`
- Execute my ansible-playbook/ansible-role for Customer2 `ansible-playbook -i inventories/customer2.ini site.yml`

Customer N:

---

What I want to do, is just create a different variables controls `vars/controls.yml` per customer:
`vars/controls-customer1.yml`
`vars/controls-customer2.yml`

And that my ansible-playbook/ansible-role is able to read it without any change (reusability).

I hope you can give me some light on this.

Thank you!

Comment: Create your inventory in `inventories/customerX/hosts.ini` and put your customer vars in `inventories/customerX/group_vars/all.yml`. You will not have to overwrite anything and vars will be loaded automagically for any hosts in your inventory.

Comment: Thanks @Zeitounator!! In this case should I edit my ‘ansible.cfg’ file or my ‘host.ini’ file to let Ansible know where to look for the variables?

Comment: No: using `-i inventories/customerX` option will be enough. https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/intro_inventory.html#organizing-host-and-group-variables

Answer (score 0):

You can also put the following into you ansible.cfg for this/these playbooks:

```
[defaults]
inventory = ./inventories/
```

Which will then load all "inventory"-files inside directory "inventories". You don't have to use the `-i` option on the command line if you don't specificly want this one specific inventory to be used.